# Efficiently handle current balance of account

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, concurrency

I've been developing an application that handles accounts and transactions made over these accounts.

Currently the tables the application uses are modelled the following way:

```
account
+----+-----------------+---------+-----+
| id | current_balance | version | ... |
+----+-----------------+---------+-----+
| 1  | 1000            | 48902   | ... |
| 2  | 2000            | 34933   | ... |
| 3  | 100             | 103     | ... |
+----+-----------------+---------+-----+

account_transaction
+------+-------------+----------------------+---------+------------------+-----+
|  id  | account_id  |          date        |  value  | resulting_amount | ... |
+------+-------------+----------------------+---------+------------------+-----+
| 101  | 1           | 03/may/2012 10:13:33 | 1000    | 2000             | ... |
| 102  | 2           | 03/may/2012 10:13:33 | 500     | 1500             | ... |
| 103  | 1           | 03/may/2012 10:13:34 | -500    | 1500             | ... |
| 104  | 2           | 03/may/2012 10:13:35 | -50     | 1450             | ... |
| 105  | 2           | 03/may/2012 10:13:35 | 550     | 2000             | ... |
| 106  | 1           | 03/may/2012 10:13:35 | -500    | 1000             | ... |
+------+-------------+----------------------+---------+------------------+-----+
```

Whenever the application processes a new transaction, it inserts a new row into *account_transaction* and, at the *account* table, it updates the column *current_balance* that store the current balance for the account and the column *version* used for optimistic locking. 
If the optimistic locking works, the transaction is commited, if it doesn't the transaction is rolled back.

As a rough example, when processing the transaction 102, the application did the 
following pseudo SQL/JAVA:

```
set autocommit = 0;

insert into account_transaction
(account_id, date, value, resulting_amount)
values
(2, sysdate(), 550, 2000);

update account set 
    current_balance = 2000, 
    version = 34933  
where 
    id = 2 and
    version = 34932;

if (ROW_COUNT() != 1) {
    rollback;
}
else {
    commit;
}
```

However certain accounts are very active and receive many simultaneous transactions which causes deadlocks at MySQL while updating the rows at *account* table. These deadlocks impose a serious performance penalty to the application since it causes the transactions to be reprocessed when deadlocks at the database occur.

How can I efficiently handle the current balance for the accounts? The current balance is needed to authorize/deny new transactions and is used in various reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I efficiently handle the current balance for the accounts?

I think this whole model is over-engineered.

Abandoning the optimistic locking through `version` and having a simple...

```
UPDATE account SET current_balance = current_balance + value WHERE id = ...
```

...at the **end** of the transaction that inserts a new `account_transaction` should be plenty fast. For data integrity, consider putting this into AFTER INSERT trigger on `account_transaction`<sup>1</sup>.

- First of all, you are doing it at the end of the transaction, so even if the transaction is long, the lock contention on this row should be short.
- SQL guarantees consistent data view within a single statement, so there is no need for separate `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.
- Also, since you are **adding** a value, instead or directly setting the sum, it doesn't really matter in which order these operations are done - addition is commutative (so shorter transactions can "overtake" the longer ones).

---

*<sup>1</sup> But be careful not to trigger it too early - only insert new `account_transaction` when it is completely "cooked", don't (for example) insert early but update the `resulting_amount` later.*

Comment: sounds good, but one question: couldn't the resulting_amount field be incorrect?  Say transaction X and Y both read current_balance and insert their account_transaction rows simultaneously.  Although the balance would be correct after both transactions, wouldn't resulting_amount be wrong for one of the rows?

Comment: @JoshNankin My answer focused on `current_balance` and it won't work so well if you need truly "serial" `resulting_amount`, as you noted. Try reversing the order of operations: first UPDATE the `current_balance`, then just copy the new balance into the new `resulting_amount`. InnoDB should lock the on UPDATE, effectively serializing the transactions (on the same `account` - other accounts can continue concurrently) and avoiding the anomaly on INSERT. This should still be plenty quick - I suggest you measure before trying to implement an optimistic locking scheme of your own.